# Insertion sort using Go

Tags: arrays, go, insertion-sort

I'm having difficulty creating a random value insert in Go, I need to do 10 tests with 1000 numbers, then 10 tests with 5000 numbers, then 10 tests with 10000 numbers, then 10 tests with 15000 ... up to 50000

I made a code with function and another code without function and the 2 are wrong

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var vetor [50000]int
    for k := 1; k <= 10; {
        k := (5 ^ k) * 1000
        for i := 1000; i < 50000; {
            vetor[i] = rand.Intn(1000)
            fmt.Print(vetor[i], ",")
        }
        start := time.Now()
        n := len(vetor)
        if n < 2 {
            return
        }
        for i := 1; i < n; i++ {
            for j := i - 1; j >= 0; j-- {
                if (vetor)[j] > (vetor)[j+1] {
                    (vetor)[j], (vetor)[j+1] = (vetor)[j+1], (vetor)[j]
                } else {
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        t := time.Now()
        decorrido := t.Sub(start)
    }
}
```

---

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func insertion(array *[]int) {
    n := len(*array)
    if n < 2 {
        return
    }
    for i := 1; i < n; i++ {
        for j := i - 1; j >= 0; j-- {
            if (*array)[j] > (*array)[j+1] {
                (*array)[j], (*array)[j+1] = (*array)[j+1], (*array)[j]
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    var vetor [50000]int
    for k := 1; k <= 10; {
        k := (5 ^ k) * 1000
        for i := 1000; i < 50000; {
            vetor[i] = rand.Intn(1000)
            fmt.Print(vetor[i], ",")
        }
        start := time.Now()
        insertion(&vetor)
        t := time.Now()
        decorrido := t.Sub(start)
    }
}
```

I also need to calculate the run time for all the tests and take the averages out of all 10 results

Comment: If you want to benchmark something, [write a benchmark](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go).

Comment: In Go, `^` is bitwise XOR, [Arithmetic operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators), [The Go Programming Language](https://golang.org/ref/spec). Therefore, the value of the expression `(5^k)` isn't what you think it is.